# Split the Filepath string folder wise

Tags: c#

Let's suppose I have an `ISample.cs` file in this path
`D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc\ISample.cs`

How can I obtain the file paths in the following way?

```
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc\ISample.cs
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you at least show the code that does everything else but split the path?

Comment: `Split` them based on "\" and ignore first 2.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
path = @"D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc\ISample.cs"

Console.WriteLine(path);

while (path != null) {
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

Output:

```
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV
D:\TEST_SOURCE
D:\
```

[Rextester Link](http://rextester.com/BBKXG15553)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Func<DirectoryInfo, IEnumerable<string>> flattenDirectory = null;
    flattenDirectory = di =>
        di == null
            ? Enumerable.Empty<string>()
            : flattenDirectory(di.Parent).Concat(new [] { di.FullName });

Func<FileInfo, IEnumerable<string>> flattenFile =
    fi => flattenDirectory(fi.Directory).Concat(new [] { fi.FullName });            

var path = @"D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc\ISample.cs";
IEnumerable<string> parts = flattenFile(new FileInfo(path));
```

That gives me:

```
D:\ 
D:\TEST_SOURCE 
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV 
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE 
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data 
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL 
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1 
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc 
D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc\ISample.cs
```

To get the output you asked for in the question just do `parts.Skip(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
List<string> filePaths = new List<string>(); // be the list to store the List
string basePath = @"D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc\ISample.cs";
filePaths.Add(basePath); 

DirectoryInfo parentInfo = Directory.GetParent(basePath);
while (parentInfo.Parent != null)
{
    filePaths.Add(parentInfo.FullName);
    parentInfo = Directory.GetParent(parentInfo.FullName);
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n",filePaths.OrderBy(x=>x.Length)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to split the path. Then with [IEnumerable.Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Split.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) you can merge it back with the desired depth:

```
var path = @"D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV\SOURCECODE\ARMY.Data\ProceduresALL\test1\abdc\ISample.cs";
var pathParts = path.Split('\\');    
var pathUpToCv = string.Join("\\", pathParts.Take(3)); //"D:\TEST_SOURCE\CV"
```

Of course, you could do this iteratively, too:

```
// This will print to console every subpath
for( int i = 1; i <= pathParts.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\\", pathParts.Take(i)));
}
```